# Join lines separated by a colon in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to re-format the text below using Python 3

```
text ="""alif
: the letter a [Sem ’-l-p (ox), Heb alef]
alifa
: be trusted, accustomed, tame 
alima
: feel pain 
"""
```

so that is outputs this way

alif : the letter a [Sem ’-l-p (ox), Heb alef]

alifa : be trusted, accustomed, tame

alima : feel pain

I tried using a solution to another problem, but can't figure out the regex

```
import re

print(re.sub('\n(:\n)','',text))
```

it just yielded the original text

Comment: `text.replace('\n:', ':')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
re.sub('\n:',':',text)
```

Your current code looks for a newline *after* the colon as well as before, but `text` has no such newlines.

Answer (score 1):

```
text ="""alif
: the letter a [Sem ’-l-p (ox), Heb alef]
alifa
: be trusted, accustomed, tame 
alima
: feel pain 
"""
print(text.replace('\n:',''))

output:
alif the letter a [Sem ’-l-p (ox), Heb alef]
alifa be trusted, accustomed, tame 
alima feel pain
```

Comment: thanks Himanshu, I gave the "tick" to Joshua coz he added an explanation, included the ":" colon in the solution and solved within the framework of regex, but I have upvoted your reply sa well coz I appreciate finding out how to do it via inbuilt functions